# Representability of Hom of two abelian schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $A$ and $B$ be abelian schemes over a base scheme $S$. There is the $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(A,B)$ functor $T \mapsto \mathrm{Hom}(A \times T, B \times T)$, where $\mathrm{Hom}$ means homomorphisms of group schemes.

> Is it true that $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(A,B)$ is representable by a scheme of locally finite presentation over $S$?

(By an abelian scheme over $S$, I mean a smooth proper group scheme over $S$, with geometrically integral fibers.)

I am ok with assuming that $S$ is locally Noetherian if necessary.

--

If the abelian schemes $A$ and $B$ are moreover projective, one can make use of representability of the Hilbert scheme. I am not sure what to do if $A$ and $B$ are just proper, and not necessarily projective.

In the answer to this question

[Representability of Hom of two finite flat group schemes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314723/representability-of-hom-of-two-finite-flat-group-schemes)

R. van Dobben de Bruyn mentions there is still an argument to show the representability of $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(A,B)$ by a scheme, but I have not yet found the argument.

Comment: Maybe one can use the algebraic space result linked in the linked answer and check some criterion for the algebraic space to be a scheme? In reasonable situations it's a disjoint union of closed subschemes of $S$, so one should have a lot of clearance to apply these criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Will Sawin for the [suggestion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419702/representability-of-hom-of-two-abelian-schemes#comment1077842_419702). That works, here are the details:

Write $\underline{\mathrm{Mor}}(A,B)$ for the functor describing morphisms of schemes (as opposed to $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(A,B)$ for morphisms of group schemes).

By [[Tag 0D1C]](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0D1C) we know that $\underline{\mathrm{Mor}}(A,B)$ is representable by an algebraic space, locally of finite presentation over $S$, and admits an open immersion into the Hilbert functor $\mathrm{Hilb}_{A \times_S B/S}$ [[Tag 0D1B]](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0D1B) (which is also an algebraic space). This Hilbert functor is separated over $S$ [[Tag 0DM7]](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0DM7), so $\underline{\mathrm{Mor}}(A,B)$ is also separated over $S$. Taking a fiber product as in the prevously linked post [https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314723/representability-of-hom-of-two-finite-flat-group-schemes] shows that $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(A,B)$ is representable by an algebraic space, which is separated and locally of finite presentation over $S$.

By the criterion in [https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4573/when-is-an-algebraic-space-a-scheme] (more precisely, the reference to Théorème A.2 in Champs Algébriques by Laumon and Moret-Bailly which says that a separated locally quasi-finite morphism of algebraic spaces is represented by schemes; alternately [[Tag 0418]](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0418)), it is enough to show that $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(A,B)$ is locally quasi-finite over $S$. For this, we reduce to the case where $S = \mathrm{Spec}~ k$ for a field $k$. In this case, one knows that $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(A,B)$ is in fact étale over $\mathrm{Spec}~k$ (rigidity for morphisms of abelian schemes), hence locally quasi-finite.

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  The Hom functor of two Abelian varieties over Spec of a field is often not quasi-finite.  Consider composition with "multiplication by $n$" isogenies (which gives a non-quasi-compact subgroup scheme).  Even worse things can happen in families.

Comment: Actually I wrote some version of this in my dissertation (§4.1) as I couldn't find a reference (but that doesn't mean that a reference doesn't exist!), exactly along the lines of this answer. DOI: [10.7916/D89K5TB0](https://doi.org/10.7916/D89K5TB0), or my [website](https://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/~dobbendebruynrvan/research.html) for a version with better typesetting.

Comment: @JasonStarr Agreed, for example if $A = B$. In the argument though, I only need locally quasi-finite rather than quasi-finite. And thanks Remy for the reference.